# How to display images in R Shiny when not saved as an R file?

Tags: r, image, shiny, shinydashboard

So when building my code, I have been writing the code in a new document, and highlighting the relevant code and clicking the run button, and then running the shinyapp function at the end. This allows me to edit bits, debug, etc. without running all the initial data pulls each time.

Something I've noticed is that images I've included in the UI file only appear on the app when I save the code is an R file and use the "Run App" feature rather than running all the code manually.

When I run the code manually, the image cannot be found and appears as the browser's missing image placeholder file.

I can't work out what I need to do to get it to show up when running the code in this manner.

Here is some example code which works and shows an image called "image.png" which is contained in the www folder. The www folder is placed in the same folder as the R file.

```
Import packages.
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)


# UI
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      id = "tabs",
      menuItem("Test", tabName="tab_data",icon=icon("table"))
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItem("tab_data",
                  fluidPage(
                    fluidRow(column(width=12,
                                    img(src='image.png', height = '50%', width = '50%', align = "left")
                    ))
                  )
            )
    )
)

# Server
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I think it is a case of it's looking in the wrong place for the file. But how do I reference the image when using the "Run" feature rather than "Run App"? I've tried placing a copy of the www folder with the image in the home directory, and that did not solve it.

Whilst I do not need to resolve this for the final app, it would be helpful in the development stage to get these images showing correctly.

Does anyone know?

Comment: When you use "run", is it perhaps executing code in a different working directory than you expect it is?

Comment: Well this is the thing - I think that's the case. When I used the source() function to import code, I need to specify the full directory of that code (excluding the "Home" part). So something like... source("Folder 1/Code.R"). When I do it via "Run App", I need to only reference the actual file name, or the sub-directory starting from the same location as the R file for the app itself. But I'm struggling to work out how to reference the image file.

Comment: Have you tried placing the image in the working directory you get from getwd(), or changing the working directory to where image.png is, or including the full path to image.png in your code?

Comment: I managed to get it working by putting the images in the home directory. (I thought I'd tried that already). Although it does not seem to work when placing them in a subdirectory, even if I reference that directory in the file path. But at least I've got it working for what I need it for

Comment: I take that back. It now is no longer working. The home directory is the result of getwd() I believe. I've tried including the full path too. So bizarre.